# Strange difference in usage of \pgfmathprintnumber

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, spacing

I encountered a strange spacing difference in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    number printer inside of fbox with -5e-5:

    \fbox{\pgfmathprintnumber{-5e-5}}

    \fbox{$\pgfmathprintnumber{-5e-5}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know that `\pgfmathprintnumber` eventually uses `\pgfutilensuremath` which is defined by

```
\def\pgfutilensuremath#1{%
  \ifmmode#1\else$#1$\fi
}
```

The question is: how can I get consistent behavior? More precisely: how can I change `\fbox{\pgfmathprintnumber{-5e-5}}` (i.e. change  `\pgfmathprintnumber`) such that it does the same as the other statement (the other way round is not  my use case).

Note that this actually a regression in pgfplots: version 1.4 used the second approach whereas version 1.5 uses the first. I would like to keep the first, but with the spacing of the second.

Could it be related to TeX's strategy to look for the next following char after `$` to see if it might be a `$$`? If so, how can I avoid it?

Comment: This seems like a bug in pgfmath. The second spacing is incorrect: it printed like `${} -5\cdot 10^{-5}$`, so I guess that pgfmath inserts an empty box somewhere.

Comment: Use  `\fbox{$$\pgfmathprintnumber{-5e-5}$$}`???

Comment: @Chuang: Never use `$$ .. $$`, see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: @Caramdir: Thanks and thanks. Should have tested that first.

Comment: @Caramdir I would agree... this is probably a bug. And I am quite happy to hear that the second is the wrong choice. But: I traced through the number printer without any clue. I would appreciate any help of volunteers (seems I am blind here).

Comment: When you are typing `\fbox{$\pgfmathprintnumber{-5e-5}$}` the fbox is not in mathmode so the conditional goes to
the `\else` part, therefore you inserting an extra `$` and you end up with math display mode within the `fbox`.  Chuang hit the nail on the head?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I will look into this. But I think that TeX will only look for ONE token to check if a `$` is actually the start of a `$$` -- and there are much more tokens between the involved math shifts. Thus, it switches to math mode and the `\ifmmode` should be true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in pgfmath. In one place it delimits a group with `{}` instead of `\begingroup ... \endgroup`. So in the second version TeX sees the `{}` inside mathmode causing it to display a binary minus instead of a unary one (try `${}-5$`; in the first version you get something like `{}$-5$` and hence unary spacing).

The problematic groups are in `\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@#1#2` and `\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@#1#2`. So to fix it you can add

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@#1#2{%
    \begingroup\toks0={#1}%
    \toks1=\expandafter{\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@e@mark #2}%
    \xdef\pgfmathfloat@glob@TMP{\the\toks0 \the\toks1 }%
    \endgroup%
    \let\pgfmathresult=\pgfmathfloat@glob@TMP
}%

\def\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@#1#2{%
    \begingroup\toks0={#1}%
    \toks1=\expandafter{\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@e@mark #2}%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/number format/@dec sep mark}\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@DEC@SEP@MARK
    \toks2=\expandafter{\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@DEC@SEP@MARK}%
    \xdef\pgfmathfloat@glob@TMP{\the\toks0 \the\toks1 \the\toks2 }%
    \endgroup%
    \let\pgfmathresult=\pgfmathfloat@glob@TMP
}
\makeatother
```

to your document.

Comment: Excellent. That fixed it. I did not know there could be such problems in using these braces as group delimiters! Thanks for your help here.

Comment: @Christian: Neither did I until a few minutes ago.

Comment: Reported the bug: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3430171&group_id=142562&atid=752792

Comment: Ah - the bug report was actually unnessary: I am responsible for the number printer and I will commit the bugfix within the next minutes.

Comment: @Christian: I should have looked at the first line of the file. :)

Comment: OK, is fixed now in PGF CVS. I found some more occurrences of the same problem in that file.